# turtlebot position fluctuates

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, position, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
Please have look on this video:
http://youtu.be/MiTcy0rHY78

I'm running turtlebot gazebo simulator, but as you see the pose of robot has lots of error and fluctuates
I have run the following:

1)roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

2)roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo gmapping_demo.launch

3)roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch

4)roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo amcl_demo.launch

The position of the robot in gazebo is fixed, but the localized position in rviz is fluctuating between several points.
what should I change to make the position of the robot stable?
Many thanks and regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203805/turtlebot-position-fluctuates/) by [Behnam Asadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5311/behnam-asadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are running multiple localization demos simultaneously. AMCL and gmapping should not be used simultaneously.

The oscillation you are seeing is a race condition between the two publishing their computed results.

It looks like you're following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it)

Make sure to follow the instructions "To be sure that all will run as expected, kill all you launched in the previous section"

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1